# AWS Lambda trigger on S3 bucket to Neptune "Failed to start new load for the source"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-neptune

I wrote a lambda function which will trigger python code when a create event happens in S3 and Python script is supposed to read files from S3 and post them to Neptune server.

When I test that, I am getting the following error.

```
{
 "requestId":"xxxxxxxx-1234-5678-9012-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",  
 "code":"ThrottlingException",  
 "detailedMessage":"Failed to start new load for the source s3://my-s3-url/file.ttl. 
    Max concurrent load limit breached. Limit is 1"
}
```

**Code:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_names = ["a.ttl", "b.ttl", "c.ttl"]
    source_url = "s3://my-s3.aws.com/"
    role = "my-role"
    neptune_url = "https://my-neptune-server.aws.com/loader"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    for name in file_names:
        file = source_url+name
        data = {"source": file, "iamRoleArn": role, "region": "region-1", "failOnError": "FALSE", "format": "turtle"}
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(post_async(neptune_url, json.dumps(data), headers))
        resp = loop.run_until_complete(task)
        print(resp)

async def post_async(neptune_url, data, headers):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(neptune_url, data=data, headers=headers) as response:
            result = await response.text()
            return result
```

I tried both Synchronous and Asynchronous ways.  I am getting limited documentation in the web.  Can some one point me right direction ?

Answer (score 3):

According to documentation: [Max concurrent load limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html) is **one**

So probably you need to introduce some queue in your upload process. Or it may be

- SQS
- preserve loading queue with file names in parameter store and recursively execute lambda function for deploying files one by one
- or you own idea... :)

Comment: I changed my logic to process one file at a time, instead of many.  Thanks for the immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/load-api-reference-load.html,

```
Max concurrent load limit breached  (HTTP 400)

If a load request is submitted without "queueRequest" : "TRUE", 
and a load job is currently running, the request will fail with this error
```

you can add the following field to your payload,

```
data = {
  "source": file, 
  "iamRoleArn": role, 
  "region": "region-1", 
  "failOnError": "FALSE", 
  "format": "turtle", 

  "queueRequest" : "TRUE"
}
```